# How to change the font size of intellisense box in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I don't know what happend here, the font size of intellisense box in vscode is too small to look clearely.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I found it in setting.json:

```json
"editor.suggestFontSize": 16
```

Comment: So that affects the initial suggestions, but not the expanded box with more details. Any ideas what that one is?