# Is it possible to set a font size in VS Code that is not in the settings?

Tags: visual-studio-code

My suggestion items have super small font and I don't know why. [Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n74gj.png).

I checked the font sizes in the settings section of VS Code, but I couldn't find this size among them its size has become imperceptibly small how can i solve this problem

Comment: Welcome! Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: Have you tried the solution mentioned here: [How to change the font size of intellisense box in VSCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55650266/how-to-change-the-font-size-of-intellisense-box-in-vscode)